# pass multiple variables on .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have this .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9A-Za-z]+)/([0-9A-Za-z]+) index.php?category=$2&language=$1&id=$3
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)=http [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ – [F,L]

Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

What I am trying to achive is to pass all variables but it seems that I cannot do that.
I am quite new in .htaccess stuff so the code might be nonsense. However, I have managed to pass the category and language, but can pass the id.

Thanks

Comment: You have only two grouped sub-patterns – so you can’t expect to get three values out of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have 2 separate rule one without id and one with id:

```
RewriteRule ^([\da-z]+)/([\da-z]+)/(\d+)/?$ index.php?category=$2&language=$1&id=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^([\da-z]+)/([\da-z]+)/?$ index.php?category=$2&language=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Answer (score 2):

It would help to study up on Perl regular expressions a tad, which is the RegEx style .htaccess uses. Links to: [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule), [RegEx info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html).

Namely, for your first RewriteRule, you only have two subgroups (the parenthetical parts) so `$3` is always going to yield empty -- whereas `$1` and `$2` will match the respective left-to-right ordered groups. Here's a sample of how to match 3 subgroups given your RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9A-Za-z]+)/([0-9A-Za-z]+)/([0-9]+) index.php?category=$2&language=$1&id=$3
```

Notice the third parenthetical part that matches one or more digits -- that matched part will be replaced into the `$3` backreference effectively subbing a numerical `id` in where you want it.

Comment: Thanks, that works fine, but the problem comes from the fact that I have ID only for the news category. the rule now expect to have id or something for all pages otherwise does not open them. Is there a way to make this rule applicable only if category is news?

Comment: Sure, you should make two rules to handle this. The first RewriteRule should be ^.../news/... ... to match news + `id` param first. Then, the second rule should be ^.../... to match just category + language without an `id`.

Answer (score 0):

If your ID is a digit then use following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9A-Za-z]+)/([0-9A-Za-z]+)/(\d+) index.php?category=$2&language=$1&id=$3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteRule ^index/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?language=$1&category=$2&id=$3 [L]
```